# UWP DependencyProperty with private setter

Tags: c#, uwp, dependency-properties

In WPF you can use `DependencyPropertyKey` to register a dependency property as readonly. However this doesn't seem to work with UWP. Is there an alternative to that or did they remove readonly dependency properties?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't there there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [DependencyProperty docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties#dependency-property-security-considerations)

> The Windows Runtime does not provide a way to register a custom dependency property as read-only.